# Is there a DNN URL decode method as it is changing a URL Encode

Tags: url-rewriting, dotnetnuke, urldecode, dotnetnuke-9

We are using Server.URLEncode to change an SKU with a forward slash from BDF5555/45 to BD5555%2F45 in our Href on a button.

[image]

When a person clicks on the button the page navigates to another module which has Request.QueryString but DNN is changing the URL.

How can I get the variable decodeprodCode to include the &45 as BDF5555/45?
Perhaps DNN is rewriting the URL?

[image]

Comment: This may be a daft question - But because it's a slash "/" - If you do manage to bring it through, won't it be trying look look for a page called "45" which lives under "BDF5555"?

Comment: The SKU is the QueryString argument which is sent to a function in the backend which will retrieve the appropriate product which is on our ERP system. Our other customers use our modules and sometimes they have got a forward slash in the SKU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `NavigateURL` class in `DotNetNuke.Common.Globals` that will generate a correct url based on a TabID and a lot of overloads.

```
DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(TabId)
```

You can also use querystring parameters

```
DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(TabId, ControlKey,"key=value"))
```

Answer (score 1):

DNN by default will re-write querystring values into /key/value format in the URL assuming that it is properly encoded.  For example if you have querystring values of sku=1 and productid = 2 the resultant URL will be

> https://yoursite.com/Your-Page/sku/1/productid/2

This is done via the FriendlyUrlProvider, but it should not have any impact to your ability to process via Request.Querystring as this is a very, very common practice for passing values into DNN.

Your code to retrieve the value is correct.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that Request.QueryString only retrieves BDF5555 and not the 45 part of the SKU as the SKU itself has a forward slash. How can I retrieve BDF5555/45?

Comment: Looking at the snippet you posted, it appears that the / isn't actually being UrlEncoded in the linking part, you might double check that part.  Otherwise, it might be worth doing a quick string replace, or set a rule to bypass the URL in the re-writer in DNN.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code instead of a Request.Querystring.

```
 string RawurlFromRequest = Request.RawUrl;
 var cleanSKU = RawurlFromRequest.Split(new[] {"sku/"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
 var CleanSKUNoOtherQueryStrings = cleanSKU.Split(new[] {"&"}, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

The Request.RawURL brings back the URL with the special characters as it is without encoding. As Mitchel Sellers mentioned above, DNN uses the FriendlyURLProvider which rewrites the URL.

For example **www.mysite.com/ProductFilter/SKU/BDF5555/45** and not 
www.mysite.com/ProductFilter/SKU/BDF5555%2F45

The CleanSKU variable will look for SKU/ and split everything on the left as it is set to [1].

After everything has been split on the left, we look for other QueryStrings which we usually add with a & sign. We will split everything on the right by setting it to [0].

This will bring back BDF5555/45 in the backend with a forward slash which we can use to retrieve product information from our ERP system which URLdecode couldn't do.